# I need help returning the next node of a doubly linked list in C

Tags: c, struct, nodes, doubly-linked-list, double-pointer

I created a doubly linked list and in the function that adds values to the list, it calls the function list_next which is supposed to return the next node in the list but I'm unable to figure out just how to do that. I feel like ListPos Pos is a double pointer hence why I wrote my code like that, but it's apparently wrong. How should I go about writing it and how would I avoid that mistake in the future?

```
struct node
{
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
    char *value;
};
typedef struct list_pos
{
    struct node *node;
} ListPos;

ListPos list_next(ListPos pos)
{
  return &(*pos.node)->next;
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: `How should I go about writing it and how would I avoid that mistake in the future?` It is a matter of style/taste. I'd say: get rid of these typedefs, they are only confusing you.

Comment: @Adele The structure ListPos is a redundant structure.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Unfortunately it's mandatory that we use it according to the assignment :(

Comment: @Adele if you tell us more about the assignment, you'll get better comments and answers.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm supposed to create a doubly linked list and fill it with letters A-Z. The current code I have is around 300 lines (main + header files combined) and I posted it on Chegg to try and get some help, but no one gave a feasible answer so I'm trying to pick it a part here on this site.

Comment: @Adele The first two answers below answer your question. If not then comment these answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code with some changes, explained in comments, which hopefully will help you:

```
struct node
{
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
    char *value;
};

// typedefs are more confusing than they are useful
struct list_pos
{
    struct node *node;
};

struct list_pos list_next(struct list_pos pos)
{
  // don't be afraid to use temp variables to make your code clearer
  struct node *current = pos.node;
  assert(current != NULL); // one way to indicate assumption
  // you could also check if current is NULL and return NULL in that case
  struct node *next = current->next;
  return (struct list_pos){next}; // compound literal to avoid temp variable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`&(*pos.node)->next` doesn't make any sense.

You probably want this:

```
ListPos list_next(ListPos pos)
{
  ListPos next;
  next.node = pos.node->next;
  return next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What Jabberwocky suggested is the right answer. I just wanted to add that you could replace

```
typedef struct list_pos
{
    struct node *node;
} ListPos;
```

with

```
typedef struct node* ListPos;
```

because you looked like you were thinking that ListPos is a pointer rather than separate struct.

Comment: They need to use the `ListPos` structure as a part of the assignment. It's in the comments.